# How much security is enough? - PHP

Tags: php, security, pdo

I am currently working on version 2 of a personal business that i started. With the first version i had issues with users sql injecting, and using xss.

Now that things are getting a bit serious ( larger amount of activity ) I took the time to learn as much as possible about sanitation, prepared statements, etc. to increase the security of my project. I know that there is no 100% fix/secure system to implement and i believe i implemented enough to guarantee plenty of security, i just want to find out if there is more i can do.

I am using PDO Prepared statements for all database interaction.

Database interaction will no longer require delete function ( users deleted tables on v1 )

I am using PHP 5.5 password_hash for passwords

All input and output is sanitized ( read through a variety of opinions on the topic code below )

```
    // Input Sanitation
    function input($input) {
        $input = trim($input);  

        $search = array(
            '@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   // Strip out javascript
            '@<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>@si',            // Strip out HTML tags
            '@<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>@siU',    // Strip style tags properly
            '@<![\s\S]*?--[ \t\n\r]*>@'         // Strip multi-line comments
        );

        if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
            $input = stripslashes($input);
        }
        return preg_replace($search, '', $input);
    }

    // Html Sanitation
    function htmlInput($input) {
        $input = trim($input);  
        return strip_tags($input, '<p><b><i>');
    }

    // Output Sanitation
    function output($input) {
        return htmlspecialchars($input);
    }

    // Url Sanitation
    function url($input){
        $input = trim($input);  
        $input = strip_tags($input);
        $input = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $input);
        $input = preg_replace("/[\/\&%#\$]/", "_", $input);
        $input = preg_replace("/[\"\']/", " ", $input);
        $output = strtolower($input);

        return $output;
    }
```

I have not decided to go with htmlpurifier due to the size. I want to stay as lightweight with everything as possible without sacrificing security.

One certain parts of the site example: Ticket system
users need to be able to create formatted text through ckeditor ( allowed tags

)
I have been having issues with sanitizing the text while keeping the allowed tags so if anyone has a solution to that i would love to hear it.

Outside of this i have created various checks, input that should be numeric go through is_numeric, login form is protected from brute force attempts and we will be using ssl for login, registration etc. ( offender ip is logged and blocked once an admin decides to do so ), images cannot be executed as php etc, and there are a variety of other things i added to attempt to secure the site. Before we relaunch i just want to ensure that i did not overlook anything.

If anyone has any resources that i could benefit from i would greatly appreciate it. I have been looking around and i believe i covered everything from what i have seen. Anyways thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Tokens/nonces in forms to prevent CSRF?

Comment: http://www.phptherightway.com/#security and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_Table_of_Contents

Comment: I have already implemented that in every form through session

Comment: Use of SSL; password reset with time limited email containing  tokenised link

Comment: If you're running a completely new version of the app, then use modern versions of PHP on your servers, so `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is irrelevant

Comment: using both, forgot password email expires every 15 min. SSL being used in login, register, shop and other important pages. Side question, is it wiser to just use ssl on the entire site? A few sites use it like paypal which is understandable but if the majority of the pages use a form and there are micro-transactions throughout the site is it worth using ssl throughout the entire site?

Comment: I use SSL for the entire site, not just for forms with confidential information; that way, you're never going to forget anything

Comment: There is no way you're going to learn everything there is to know about security in a question and comments on SO. Nor can you validate that all of your security-minded modifications or methodologies have been implemented correctly. Security is inherently based on time, cost and risk, and right now you sound like you're constrained by risk (your lack of real capabilities, however transient). If you have the money, hire an experienced developer to review your site's code. This is the amount of security you should have (what you can afford, based on what's at risk, given time constraints).

Comment: Thank you for the link btw i haven't seen that yet. Decided to learn php a few months ago so i am trying to soak up as much as possible.

Comment: Why don't you use `strip_tags` with no second argument for your `input()` function as well? Not using a whitelist but a blacklist _can_ be problematic.

Comment: @jaredFarrish Since the development of the site took so long the resources that we currently have are nearly exhausted. Once the site is live and we are able to recover a bit i planned on hiring someone with more experience to look over the site and tell me what is wrong etc. This will be for the increased security as well as the learning experience for myself.

Comment: @julian I added strip tags now, i didnt realize it was missing until you mentioned.

Comment: regenerate session ids at least on successful login and logout to prevent session spoofing

Comment: @markBaker Already done on both.

Comment: While this is an interesting topic, it's not a great fit for this site in the way you've framed it: you're explicitly soliciting either an extended discussion, or links to offsite resources, whereas this site is specifically engineered for dealing with questions with specific, comprehensive answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your points are already the most important ones, additionally you can do this:

1. Use HTTPS for the whole site, this avoids lots of problems, see also SSL-strip.
2. Add the **X-Frame-Options** to the HTTP header of your login page, so that the page cannot be shown inside an iframe. This can help against clickjacking. In PHP this would look like that: `header('X-Frame-Options: DENY');`.
3. Add the **Content-Security-Policy** to the HTTP header of your login page. If a browser supports CSP, this can be an effective protection against Cross-Site-Scripting. In PHP it would look like this: `header("Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';");`.
4. Remove inline JavaScript and place it to external *.js files. This makes the CSP more effective.
5. Regenerate the session id on the login page, to make session fixation more difficult.
6. Should your site be HTTPS only, then you can add the **HTTP Strict Transport Security** header. The HSTS can prevent users (that already visited your site once), from calling unsecure HTTP pages. This can help against SSL-strip.

Of course there is a lot more one can do, i would for example separate validation (test if input is as expected) and escaping (as late as possible only for the given output type). Sanitizing the input is a bit questionable, either it is valid or not, then i would reject it.

Comment: @martinstoechli i will be working on all of your points. For every form everything is validated. For example if the form contains a drop down the value runs through in_array, integers are checked through is_numeric, i took care of all of that for each form already.

Comment: @ICJ - Good to hear. If you really have to switch between HTTP and HTTPS, then you could work with a second authentication cookie, as described [here](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#ssl_nomim_cookie), but i would prefer HTTPS for the whole site.

Comment: With the direction i am going with making various forms available through notifications i am just going to use https throughout the entire site. I rather protect all user data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use PEAR validate package to validate any type of inputs. That's much more reliable than using simple functions to validate inputs.

As you mentioned security is never 100% guaranteed but SSL makes has the ability to stop session hijacking. As you have a ticket system it's better to use SSL. If you concerns the speed of your website you can just run your Login part on the https protocol

Good luck

Comment: if you only run the login part in HTTPS someone can get your logged-in session ID once you switch back to HTTP

Comment: By That i mean the control panel of your website ! All you need is to set session on the HTTPS parts ! You don't need all your website to set users information ! running all the site on HTTPS is the best solution but when it comes to speed of your website this might be expensive.

Comment: When logged in user is given a token and key that is logged in db and is created by ip and timestamp of login ( hashed with bcrypt ) if the token and key do not match the user is logged out and token is emptied from db.

Comment: That's a nice Idea but as you asked for more security i suggested using SSL which encode all your data.

Comment: @ICJ if you're using HTTP the token and key will be sent 'in the clear' and can be accessed by anyone with the right equipment.

Comment: That's the case @serakfalcon Thanks for the note

Comment: The built in [filter extension](http://php.net/filter) would be worth a look too, rather than rolling your own solutions.

Comment: @serakfalcon I will be using https Token uses the ip address of the user who was logged would it be worth verifying that the logged in user's ip matches the tokens ip? I avoided this because i know for example students in dorms are on campus internet which cycles ip and i didnt want to force them to login in over and over.

Comment: @ICJ In my programs I check the useragent but not the IP for that reason. Reality is, either could be spoofed, but if you're using SSL (the S in https), and regenerate the session after login, in conjunction with your token/key is the best you can do without making things much more complicated, and should be secure enough for most purposes. A more robust approach could involve classifying IP's (say by country) and logging out if the IP's are sufficiently different... nonces... there's always some way to be more secure!